# embedded C programming issue for 8051 MCU

Tags: c, embedded, 8051

I am studying 8051 MCU programming and I am now doing a mini project of LED flashing. What I want to do is that when I press the button, the LED will flash slower. Conversely, when I release the button, the LED will flash faster. I used embedded C and here is my code:

```
#include <reg51.h>

sbit LED = P0^0;
sbit SW = P1^0;


void T0delay(int num);

void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        LED = ~LED;
        if (SW == 0)
        {
            T0delay(4);
        }
        else
        {
            T0delay(2);
        }
    }
}

void T0delay(int num)
{
        **unsigned char i;
        unsigned char a;**
        for (a=0;a<num;a++)
        {
            for (i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                TMOD = 0x01;
                TL0 = 0xFE;
                TH0 = 0xA5;
                TR0 = 1;
                while (TF0 == 0);
                TR0 = 0;
                TF0 = 0;
            }
        }               
}
```

But I found that when I declared the variable a and i as 0 outside the for loop, the LED will flash faster.

```
#include <reg51.h>

sbit LED = P0^0;
sbit SW = P1^0;


void T0delay(int num);

void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        LED = ~LED;
        if (SW == 0)
        {
            T0delay(4);
        }
        else
        {
            T0delay(2);
        }
    }
}

void T0delay(int num)
{
        **unsigned char i = 0;
        unsigned char a = 0;**
        for (a;a<num;a++)
        {
            for (i;i<num;i++)
            {
                TMOD = 0x01;
                TL0 = 0xFE;
                TH0 = 0xA5;
                TR0 = 1;
                while (TF0 == 0);
                TR0 = 0;
                TF0 = 0;
            }
        }               
}
```

Can anyone explain why it performs like this? is there anything wrong in my declaration way causing this result? What is the good practice for a professional engineers to declare the variable? Sorry for my poor English. Please let me know in case there is any unclear in my question. Thank you!

Comment: these two statements: `for (a;a<num;a++)
        {
            for (i;i<num;i++)` will cause the compiler to output two warnings messages about the first parameter being a 'do nothing'.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: Why are there two nested loops rather then one incrementing to `num * num`, although a delay that runs for the square of its input is an odd design in any case.  Don't post code that will not compile; if you want to highlight areas of code, use valid comments.

Comment: `num` is an `int`, but `i` and `a` are `char`.  This code is easily broken by passing `num` of say 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By initialising `i` once only, it is not reset for the next iteration of the `a` loop.

```
for (i; i < num; i++)
```

On the second and subsequent loop, `i` will start at `num`. This is why you need

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

So that `i` loops from `0` on every occasion.

But the initial loop value of `a` is set only once, so it doesn't matter whether that is when `a` is defined, or in the first loop condition.

Comment: @Honlo : This is not a "comment", it is an _answer_, which you have paraphrased in a comment unnecessarily.  Just up-vote and/or accept - do not add "thank you" comments - that is not the SO way.